# Filter Number in an angular object using limitto

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-limitto, array.prototype.map

I am using a angularjs filter method on an repeated array of items and trying to filter numbers with a limitTo filter. The result is not getting applied to the repeat in the DOM.

Here is the html

```
<div ng-controller="demo as d">
      <input type="text" ng-model="d.test" ng-change="d.filterthis(d.test)"><br>
      <div ng-repeat="item in d.items | limitTo:d.limitto  track by $index">
            <span ng-show="!item.show">{{item.myno}}</span> - 
            <span ng-show="!item.show">{{$index}} - {{item.mystr}}</span><br>
      </div>
</div>
```

App.js filter function withing angularjs

```
this.filterthis = function(filter){
    that.items.map(function(filter){

            return function(obj){
                obj.show=true;
                if(obj.myno.toString().indexOf(filter) >-1){
                    console.log(obj);
                    obj.show=false;
                }
                return obj;
            }
    }(filter));
};
```

Items is a array like this

```
this.items = [{
        show:false,
        myno:10,
        mystr:"test1"
    }];
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/bTdlTpSeZuPyGpolXLEG

Comment: are you trying to not return items that have `show:true` applied based upon the values in the input field?

Comment: That was an inverse. Sorry for that method of usage. You can take show===hide and then have a look at it. The filter is my issue. Please check the plunkr

Comment: ng-show="!item.show"

Comment: right, but are you trying to just show the first three items that you're searching for? and not show any of the ones that dont match the search text?

Comment: yes. if i search for 19 it should show 19 and if I search for 1 it should show first three of all the searches starting with 1 limiting to 3 items

Comment: and you just want to search the `myno` key, the `mystr` key or both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having "show" as a key on your items, doesnt remove it from the `ng-repeat`, and so the `limitTo` filter will still return the items. Instead you should leverage the [`filter`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter) filter in the repeat like so

```
<input type="text" ng-model="d.search"><br>
<div ng-repeat="item in d.items | filter:{myno:d.search} | limitTo:d.limitto track by $index">
    <span>{{item.myno}}</span> - 
    <span>{{$index}} - {{item.mystr}}</span><br>
</div>
```

Note that order is important here, if you `limitTo` and then `filter` you are only filtering the limit'ed result. You can change the key upon which you filter by changing `{myno:d.search}` to a different key, alternatively if you want to search the whole object, simply use `d.search`.

**[Updated Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/sDO1mtJAfMxm8H9Azm1H?p=preview)**

Comment: Ok cool. I had a multiple filter implementation and didnt use the filter based on object. Now works great. This was my actual need converted. Thanks a ton... haxxxton. ;-) http://plnkr.co/edit/bQh4MoOfTAx7IsMquswZ